# Can we get google map by Route Specifying route type?

Tags: android, google-maps

friends,

i am opening google map application by using intents and URL to google maps.
now i want to specify route type for example : bus,plane,foot etc..(supported by google map)

is it possible or not?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible you have pass Parameter for this in the Google map URl.

GO through this link fro Google map URL parameter and pass the type of route you need in your map
http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters